# Open source implementation of Multiscale Combinatorial Grouping

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision, image-processing, python

I would like to use [Multiscale Combinatorial Grouping](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/mcg/) for my PhD research. However, I am restricted to use open-source implementations and this one runs on Matlab.

Does anyone know of an equivalent **contour detection method** that works on large images that is implemented **open-source**, preferably in Python?

Here some more background info. Equivalent methods would be:

- [Contour detection and hierarchical image segmentation](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html) -> cannot handle images of more than 1000x1000 pixels and runs on Matlab
- [SLIC Superpixels](https://ivrl.epfl.ch/research/superpixels) -> creates too many redundant segments

I am interested in detecting contours of visible objects in drone imagery with a resolution of 2-5cm per pixel and extents of up to 1kmx1km for the purpose of automating cadastral mapping. Here an example of what the contour detection output should look like:

[image]

Comment: Programming and tool/library requests are offtopic here. Afaik, they are anywhere on SE, but I suspect you might get help in our [chat] or maybe that of [scicomp.SE].

Comment: "I am restricted to use open-source implementations and this one runs on Matlab" -- Kudos to the person who made that decision!

Comment: Okay, sorry for posting off-topic. I now repostet my question in [Computational Science] (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/open-source-implementation-of-multiscale-combinatorial-grouping) I will forward the Kudos to my PhD supervisors.

Comment: No harm done, good luck!